# android:How to get call backs from service to activity?

Tags: android, callback, android-service

I am using a service to upload a file to server and I am getting some result after file uploaded I want some call backs from service like when upload completed, when got result, if didn't got result in specific time, when network lost etc. as per these call backs I need changes in my activity from where my service was called. currently I am using different-different broadcast send and receive like this.

```
Intent w = new Intent("<KEY>");
w.putExtra("***", ***);
sendBroadcast(w);
```

It is working fine now but I want to know that it is proper way to do such or is there any better way?
I also red about pass Handler from activity and pass message queue from service but I am not comfortable this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BroadcastReceivers` is perfectly fine.
But if your worker upload-thread needs to run once-off time, then an AsyncTask may better suits your needs. You do your work in `doInBackground` and then use `onPostExecution()` to update your GUI.

As you said, you can also use a Handler inside your Activity. But then your Service will need to be a bound Service in order for you to be able to pass the Handler to the Service.

For very simple things, I'd advise you to use an AsyncTask.